# PostgreSQL return a JSON from JSON column with only key/values for which the key is in a python list

Tags: python, json, postgresql, jsonb

Suppose that I have some PostgreSQL table ('table_1') that I want to select from in a Python script. This table has a column with JSON data (called 'json_data') like the following, e.g.:

```
{'4369': 2, '8465': 1, '12561': 1, '12562': 1}
```

Now I have a list in Python that looks the following:

```
[4369, 8465, 12561, 16657]
```

And my goal is to return a JSON/dict from the postgresql table that only contains key/value pairs for which the key is in the Python list for each row. For the above, I would thus expect a JSON returned as:

```
{'4369': 2, '8465': 1, '12561': 1}
```

My guess is that it has to look somewhat like this, but I have no clue what has to go at the '...'

```
SELECT json_data ->> ... IN 'python_list'
FROM table_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSONB_OBJECT_AGG()`, `JSONB_EACH()` and `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function together within a SELECT Statement which includes JOINs in order to match elements of the dict object with the keys of JSON object  such as

```
SELECT JSONB_OBJECT_AGG( j1.key, j1.value ) AS js_data
  FROM table_1 t
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH(json_data) AS j1 
  JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS('[4369, 8465, 12561, 16657]'::JSONB) AS j2
    ON j2.value::INT = j1.key::INT
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c12294c0d9168fdb3f6c176521d295d)</kbd>

*P.S:* I've preferred `JSONB`, *which stores data in a decomposed binary form and faster to process* , data type. For `JSON`, check out the following

<kbd>[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=371552aff77b3fe0510d0dd59f792829)</kbd>

Comment: JSONB makes imho only sense when you need indexes on this data as well, for faster searching. Otherwise it takes more storage space and is slower on INSERT's. I don't think our examples can use an index.

Comment: you're right @FrankHeikens , that will depend on the OP'S choice.

Comment: With some tweaking, this gets me where I have to be. Both good answers though :)

Answer (score 1):

Example, just in plain SQL and using a CTE to mimic your table:

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT  '{"4369": 2, "8465": 1, "12561": 1, "12562": 1}'::json AS json_data
)
SELECT  *
FROM    i, -- your table name
        json_each(json_data)
WHERE   key::int =any(ARRAY[4369, 8465, 12561, 16657]);
```

The function json_each (or jsonb_each when using jsonb data type) does the trick.

I hope you can transform this into something useful in python.

Comment: OP clearly states that the expected result is of the form `{'4369': 2, '8465': 1, '12561': 1}`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: You're right, forgot that part